# What is the error with this SQL insert statement?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `api_key` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `platform` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `key_type` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

INSERT  INTO api_key (key,key_type,platform,user_id,id) values ('123', '0', '00', '123', 'c89116d2');
```

Always output:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'key,key_type,platform,user_id,id) values ('123', '0', '00',
>   '123', 'c89116d2')' at line 1

Comment: id column should be integer and use backticks for reserve kewords

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal But that still doesn't explain the error AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`key` is a reserved keyword in MySQL, and you should avoid using it as a name for columns, tables, etc. (read: don't use if at all possible).  However, you can get around this problem by escaping the column name `key` with backticks.  Try the following `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO api_key (`key`, `key_type`, `platform`, `user_id`, `id`)
VALUES ('123', '0', '00', '123', 'c89116d2');
```

Note that I escaped all columns in backticks for consistency, though only the `key` column should require it to make the `INSERT` work.